# Sdk path issue when a project created from one machine is copied to another machine

Tags: android, ios, windows, flutter, sdk

When I move my code from one machine to another, I have to get the SDK path issue. I set SDK path but it doesn't work

Comment: delete your pubspec.lock and other .* files in the root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Windows as your development OS, then make sure you add the Flutter SDK to your `PATH` variable.
[image]

And follow further instructions here: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows